# onClick is not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have a slider menu which I want by clicking on that another page loaded. in firefox its works but I want to works my HTML in any browsers? could you please help me? thanks.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div >
    <a href="#" id="link1" >Vertical link 1</a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    $("#link1").on("click", function () {
    $("#content").load("test.html");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">A</th>
                <th scope="col">B</th>  
                <th scope="col">C</th> 
                <th scope="col">D</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>         
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not able to produce it. Can you share any fiddle where it's not working?

Comment: i have revised the question, i want to load another page by clicking

Comment: Can't you simple put test.html in href of the anchor? Isn't it available?

Comment: it is possible but I want to put the other HTML page into some content in main HTML, do you have s solution for this?

Comment: Can you please check, I think it's cross origin issue which usually creates problem in chrome. onClick is working, but you won't be able to load the file due to cross origin issue.

Comment: Check the console is that seems to be a problem you can correct it using a small chrome app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/related?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to work!

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="link1" >Vertical link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link2" >Vertical link 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="link3" >Vertical link 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="link4" >Vertical link 4</a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
       $('.wrapper').children().on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it is work on firefox but not chrome. this is the error on chrome:"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://C:/test/test.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Comment: @alex it means you should run this on a server, not on your file system

Answer (score 0):

If the content is dynamic then it needs to be delegated :

```
$(document).on("click", "#link1" , function () {
    console.log('click')
    $("#content").load("./resources/link1.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to http://api.jquery.com/load/ you will notice this line :

Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

So basically if you want to use load you should fire it up from a server.

try this if you have installed python3 on a command prompt :

python3 -m http.server 9000

Then open browser and navigate to http://localhost:9000. Click on the link it will work.

You can do this from any server but for load to work you should fire up your page from a server.

This is only in chrome.